# Django Rest Framework : Fields are not getting create or update after making custom methods inside models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
        user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name = "First Name")
    user_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name = "Last Name")
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, verbose_name = "Email Id")
    user_dob = models.DateField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name = "Date of Birth")
    user_mobileno = models.CharField(max_length=14, verbose_name = "Contact No")
user_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_location, 
    null=True,
    blank=True, 
    width_field = "width_field", 
    height_field = "height_field", verbose_name = "Profile Picture")
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name = "Password")
    user_blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name = "Blood Group")
    user_location_id = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name = "Current Location")
    user_profession = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name = "Profession")
    user_fb_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name = "Facebook Contact", blank=True)
    user_random_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name = "Registration Id")
    user_created_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add=False)
    user_updated_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add=False)

    def get_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user_firstname, self.user_lastname)

   def __str__(self):
            return "%s %s" % (self.user_firstname, self.user_lastname)
```

Not when i made following post request, it's saving user_firstname & lastname and even not updating. And get_name method returning " ".

Folowing is my serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(source='get_name')
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ['user_id','name']
```

Can anyone help to out this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the parameters for creating object according to name defined in serializer that will work as you have desired make sure you pass values for all the parameters that can not be null. Now incase you want user to pass the parameter name instead of user_firstname &  user_lastname you will need to get the value for name while creating & split name to get firstname & lastname & assign it to user_firstname &  user_lastname.